# Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\netupdate.php on line 21

Tags: php, html

I am facing some weird problem. Here is my file upload snipped of the form through which I am trying to upload the image to my server

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image">
```

And I am getting the error:

```
Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\netupdate.php on line 21
```

My upload script is as following

```
// file upload scrpt 
  $name= $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
  $type = $_FILES['image']['type']; 
  $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
  $pathAndName = "file:///c:/wamp/www/upload/networking/".$name;
  $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $pathAndName);
```

Now the weird portion is that all other parameters are being accepted in the php script other than the image, I am writing everything to my database and its giving a success message but only this portion is giving errors and even weirder part is that a similar script is working perfectly in other mysql table so I guess there is nothing wrong in php_ini.

Comment: If this is occuring on an iOS device or other mobile device, this occurs because mobile browsers disable the file select fields and therefore, $_FILES['image'] does not exist. Also make sure you are selecting a file before going to this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>` element.

```
<form action="netupdate.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I guess I have over worked today, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form tag

```
<form id="xx" name="xxx" action="xxx.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks boss, I turn out to be a real dumb a** sometimes, thanks a lot